# What does the auth keyword in request.get() do?

Tags: python, api, request, python-requests

When making a GET request from an API, I have seen the following (requests module):

```
requests.get(url, auth=(username, password)
```

What exactly does this auth keyword do? What happens if it isn't included?

Answer (score 1):

It is for http basic auth to go along with your API request.

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/

If it requires authentication and you don't provide any, your request will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The `auth` keyword is for HTTP authentication, aka the value of the `Authorization` header. When passed a tuple, it will perform [HTTP basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).